# Uniformly convergence of delta sequences

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n) $ be a sequence of continuous functions $f_n: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x) \phi(x) dx=\phi(0)
$$ 
for each continuous compactly supported function $\phi :\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.
Is it then $(f_n)$ uniformly convergent to $0$ on each $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$  ?

Comment: You meant $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x)\phi(x)\,dx = \phi(0)$, didn't you?

Comment: Note $\text{sgn}(a) = \text{sgn}(b)$ in your formulation, so it means locally uniform convergence.
$(f_n)_n$ has properties similar to that of an approximate unit

Comment: No, that need not be. You could have $f_n$ have  a triangle of height $1$ and width $2^{-n}$ located at all integers $\neq 0$.